# Detecting WebPage in WebView Control

Tags: android

How to check whether a web page is opened in external browser or web view control using javacode in android?

Answer (score 0):

An idea:
Add one more View to your layout file where you have the WebView control. This view will serve as a flag. Set it's visibility to be GONE.

Then in your activity try to get a reference to it. If it returns null - it means the view cannot be found so you are in the external browser, otherwise you are in your custom layout.

Comment: what activity if he is talking about web page? If he has an activity, then he definitely knows where it is opened

Comment: The revers of what you said will be: If he DOES NOT have an activity, then he definitely knows that he is an external Web Page, which makes the question to be without any sense.

Comment: No, fact that he has no activity doesn't prove that page is opened in "external web browser", it may be opened in web view. But yes, without any external flag there is no way to check is it external browser or not.